# loading overlay while ajax call in jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

Hi I want to add an effect in jsp @ center of page while I am performing an ajax call for loading my drop down.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing your code. But there are a number of ways to produce a "loading" mask in javascript. It depends on which javascript libraries you have. I'll give an example of this with an Ext.LoadMask:

```
// First param of LoadMask constructor is the element to display the load mask over.
myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {
    msg:"Please wait..."
});

myMask.show();
// Perform ajax call to load data ... something like
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            // Your code populates the dropdown with the response ...
            // Then hide the mask when data is loaded
            myMask.hide();
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl/data",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```